# Representation of If-Then As Or

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to gain a deeper understanding of the relationship between `if p then q` and `not p or q`.

`p → q == ~p v q`

The example that is in the book I am reading for this situation is as follows:

```
Rewrite the following statement in if-then form:

"Either you get to work on time or you are fired."

Let ~p be "You get to work on time"

and q be "You are fired."

Then the given statement is ∼p ∨ q. Also p is "You do not get to work on time."

So the equivalent if-then version, p → q, is "If you do not get to work on time, then you are fired."
```

This makes sense to me when I read it, but I cannot reproduce it myself unless I follow their specific formula, neither do I have a very deep understanding at all of this relationship.

```
For example if I try to convert from `p → q` into `~p v q`:

"If I go to maths class, then I will understand maths."

let p = "I go to maths class"
let q = "I will understand maths"

So ~p v q should be:

"I do not go to maths class or I will understand maths."
```

Comment: It sounds wonky but it is correct. You can think of it as either p is not true or q is. The statement is true because if p is true then you know q is.

Comment: There are 4 possible T/F combinations for p and q  ;TT,TF,FT,FF. The sentence "if p then q" asserts that the second one (TF) does not hold.The second one is also the only one that violates "not-p or q". ....BTW..Note that if p has been proven to be false ,the sentence "p implies q" is true, but yields no information about q. For example, if p is "1=0" and q is "You are rich."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### "If P, then Q" Vesus.  "Either not P or Q."

We know that "either P or not P" is true. There's no middle.

Now "If P, then Q" means that Q always happens when P does.   So thence two things which can happen are: "Either Q or not P."

Now "Either Q or not P" means that if P is true then Q must be too.   This is "If P, then Q".

Thus they are equivalent.

Note that neither statement exclude the possibility of P being false when Q is true.  However, both statements prohibit P being true and Q being false.

That is all.

---

Repeating using you example statements.

> We know that "either you go to math class or you do not go to math class." There's no middle; they are complementary.
>
> Now "If I go to maths class, then I will understand maths" means that you will understand maths if you happens to go to maths class.   So thence the two things which can happen are: "Either you understand maths or you didn't go to class."
>
> Now "Either you understand maths or you didn't go to class." means that if you do go to class then you will understand maths.   This is "If I go to maths class, then I will understand maths".
>
> Thus they mean the same thing.
>
> Neither statement excludes the possibility that you will understand maths when you do not go to class, but neither do they assert that you won't understand maths if you don't go to maths class.
>
> However, both statements prohibit the possibility that you fail to understand maths when you go to maths class.

Now, do you understand maths?

Answer (score 0):

I just happened to read the same book and faced the same challenge in understanding this equivalence however, I realize that If you apply commutativity on `~p v q`  then the equivalence becomes obvious.

Rather then

`p -> q == ~p v q`, just do
`p -> q == q v ~p`. I will understand maths or I don't go to school.
In other words, if I go to school then I will understand maths.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).